# APBS installation error in ubuntu20

Tags: github

I am trying to install APBS in my machine using instructions given in-
https://apbs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting/source.html#get-source-directly-from-github

When I executed `cmake ..` command

Error output in screen looks something like this:

```
.
.
.
.
-- APBS Libraries: maloc;punc;mc;gamer;superlu;vf2c;m;stdc++;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libumfpack.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspqr.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcholmod.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libccolamd.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcamd.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcolamd.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libamd.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.a;-lpthread;-lm;-ldl;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsuitesparseconfig.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.a;TABIPBlib;GeometricFlowLib
-- Internal Libraries: apbs_generic;apbs_pmgc;apbs_mg;apbs_fem;apbs_geoflow_apbs;apbs_routines
--  
--  -fPIC
-- Building documentation enabled
-- ================================================================
-- ================================================================
-- Supplemental tools enabled
-- Building mesh
-- libraries: apbs_generic;apbs_mg;apbs_pmgc;apbs_fem
-- Building manip
-- libraries: apbs_generic;apbs_mg;apbs_pmgc;apbs_fem
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/psl-1/Documents/apbs/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/psl-1/Documents/apbs/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
(base) psl-1@psl1-H410M-H:~/Documents/apbs/build$
```

I can't pinpoint what's the error. I reached here by fixing several I received while executing `cmake ..` command. From here on I can't understand what to do next.

Comment: Are you really using a Ubuntu Core 20 system?  or a 20.04 system?  Please clarify your product/release details as 20 & 20.04 are different products.

Comment: Did you look at the:"`See also`" files?

Comment: Your link : "Caution .... We do not recommend cloning directly from the head of the master branch because it is typically under development and could be unstable. .... we advise you to skip the next step." .... Solution : You can use the binary version `APBS-3.4.0.Linux.zip` https://github.com/Electrostatics/apbs/releases/download/v3.4.0/APBS-3.4.0.Linux.zip .... Ref. https://github.com/Electrostatics/apbs/releases